# What is the name of the river that flows through Ponyville?

Tags: my-little-pony, my-little-pony-fim

Most of the maps of Equestria show a river flowing through Ponyville but I have not found one where the river is named (see example below).

What is the name of the river that flows through Ponyville?

[image]

Comment: Yay to pony questions!

Comment: @Gallifreyan you commented but didn't upvote?!?   :)

Comment: Out of votes for today :( Will up vote tomorrow, promise!

Comment: @Gallifreyan wow that's impressive.  That's never happened to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The river that runs through Ponyville is *... [drum roll, please](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ek56AgxwybI) ...* the **Ponyville River**.

[image]
<sub><sup>[MLP: Spirit of the Forest #2](https://mlp.fandom.com/wiki/My_Little_Pony:_Spirit_of_the_Forest)</sup></sub>

As you can imagine, I was flustered and consternated to learn this..